# Updating a field while editing another

Tags: qgis

When creating a feature, I want that, if I change the value of field A that field B is also updated with the same value, like an `onChange` event.

For Example: Imagine you have a basket of apples and field A contains the max amount of apples that fit in the basket. Field B is the current amount of apples in the basket. So when I create the feature "basket" I want that the basket is always full. This means, that the max amount is equal to the current amount. So if I enter the max amount it should also set the same number to the current amount.

In the end, I just want to save time to tip the number twice.
Any idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a default value for the column that needs a value from another column. Default values can be set in Layer Properties > Attribute Forms.

Please note the default value only apply when creating records and not when updating records, if you also need update copy use a virtual field like in Dror Bogins answer.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use a virtual field that copies the data from column A to Column B.

[image]

If I define my field like that, whenever I create a new feature or update the "Apples" column, then "Current N Apples" will also update.

When I create a new feature I can enter only one number and get the value in the new column:
[image]
[image]